# onclickListeners not working for two different ImageView

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have two Images in my main activity where i want to display new activities for each image click. When I click on the first Image it starts the second activity(Image2.class) rather than starting the first activity(Image1.class). Why is this happening? I want to display Image1.class Activity when I click on image1. likewise Image2.class Activity when I click on image2.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity   {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Image1.class);
                intent1.putExtra("image1Desc", "Text Description for IMAGE1!!!!!!!!!");
                startActivity(intent1);
                finish();
            }
        });

        image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Image2.class);
                intent2.putExtra("image2Desc", "Text Description for IMAGE2!!!!!!!");
                startActivity(intent2);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Main Activity XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/b" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Image1.class Activity XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Image1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/image1text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewZoom1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Image2.class Activity XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Image2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/image2text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewZoom2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:src="@drawable/b" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imageanimation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.imageanimation.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.imageanimation.Image1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_image1" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.imageanimation.Image2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_image2" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: the code seems ok .. check if you put correct image in xml

Comment: Post your xml also, you may have confused with the ids of Imageview's

Comment: will you show your xml ?

Comment: i've uploaded the xml

Comment: I've found the issue which is a simple matter.

imageView2 of MainActivity XML was overlapping on top of ImageView1 which is not visible. After I re-sized it the problem was solved. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue which is a simple matter.

imageView2 of MainActivity XML was overlapping on top of ImageView1 which is not visible. After I re-sized it the problem was solved.

In Main Activity XML

```
<ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView2"
         android:layout_width="200dp"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
         android:src="@drawable/b" />
```